# SVG Rendering Issue in androidsvg Library

Tags: android, image, svg, render

I hope this message finds you well. I want to start by expressing my gratitude for your work on the [androidsvg](https://github.com/BigBadaboom/androidsvg) library. It has been a valuable library for our development efforts.

I am writing to report an issue we've encountered while using [androidsvg](https://github.com/BigBadaboom/androidsvg) . We are currently developing a product that involves editing SVG images on both Android and iOS platforms. we have been facing some challenges on Android. please review attached images.

The problem we're experiencing is related to SVG rendering. It appears that certain SVGs are not rendering correctly on Android devices, resulting in visual inconsistencies.

We have thoroughly reviewed our implementation and confirmed that the issue seems to be rooted in the [androidsvg](https://github.com/BigBadaboom/androidsvg)  library itself, as the SVGs in question are well-formed and display correctly on other platforms.

We are eager to continue using [androidsvg](https://github.com/BigBadaboom/androidsvg)  for our Android development, but this rendering issue is currently a roadblock for us. We would greatly appreciate your assistance in resolving this matter or any guidance you can provide to help us better understand and address the issue.

If needed, we can provide specific SVG files and additional details to help diagnose the problem. We understand that open-source projects require time and effort, and we are more than willing to assist in any way we can to resolve this issue.

#### **Android SVG Image :**

[image: Android_SVG]

#### **IOS SVG Image :**

[image: IOS_SVG]

#### **SVG String :**

[content_hide_svg.txt](https://github.com/BigBadaboom/androidsvg/files/12514061/content_hide_svg.txt)

Thank you for your attention to this matter, and we look forward to your guidance.

Comment: It's the viewBox you are using that will cause the same effect everywhere. Please try `viewBox="-150 -65 300 300"`

Comment: Hi @enxaneta this worked but how did you calculate the view box value? Can you give me a step?

Comment: I did it with javascript. Unfortunately I have no idea how to do it in android. You need to look for a way to calculate the bounding box of the main group

Comment: please share your javascript code calculation

Comment: Supposing that G is the group wrapping everything you can do: `let bb = G.getBBox()`. This will return an object with the x, y, width and height of the bounding box of the group. You can use those values + some extra margin for the viewBox attribute: viewBox="x y width height"

Comment: Thank you @enxaneta Let's we will try in android